# Star Schema design for organ donation

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema

I need some help in starting a new dimensional model (star schema) for tracking organ donors. We have an OLTP database that contains a referrals table (terminology for deaths) with info such as (gender, race, age, date of death) and related lookup tables, e.g.,date,time, race, hospital, organ type, donated organ info, etc. Some of the referrals become organ donors. I understand that most of the lookup tables will become the dimension tables but wondering if I should have 2 fact tables - factReferralInfo and factOrganDonors or only 1 fact table to track everything. We may have queries such as 'total number of referrals', 'total kidney donors', etc.

After thinking about it, I guess I need a dimension dimReferral that has the attributes for each death referral. I think I am confused since I read that you should not have a dimension table the same scope as the fact table. Maybe in the fact table, I have a row for each organ donated, e.g., kidney, pancreas, lung, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a referral can donate multiple organs. This would be a one-to-many relationship between referrals and donations. Because of this, I would say donations should be the grain of your fact table and referrals would be a dimension. The following rough sketch is how I would begin to approach it:

[image: Rough sketch of donation as fact table]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. I was thinking later that referrals should be a dimension. We have many reports that look at referral analysis that have no donations (referrals have many attributes such as medical suitable, consent info, etc.). So is this star design good for those queries? Because we get a call for every death, this is an event and why the referral table is the main table in our ER design. Also, since we have tissue donors which have different measures, I guess we can have 2 fact tables - organdonations and tissuedonations with conformed dimensions. I am right in this thinking?

Comment: Since organs and tissues have different measures (and likely different dimension attributes) you would probably have Fact_Organ_Donations, Fact_Tissue_Donations, Dim_Organs, and Dim_Tissues. In order to do more complex analysis on referrals who didn't donate such as "Which referrals donated organ X but not tissue Y?" then you would need an additional special kind of fact table usually referred to as a [coverage factless fact table](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1996/09/02/factless-fact-tables/).